# Компиляция Pug (Jade) в .tpl

Tags: node.js, gulp, jade, pug

Здравствуйте. Надо переделать один сайт, там шаблоны `smarty` с расширением `tpl`. Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить `gulp-jade`, чтобы он компилировал шаблоны `*.jade` в файлы `*.tpl`, а то он только в `*.html` создает.

Почему-то нигде не нашел, неужели нет такой настройки?

Comment: Нету. Иначе это был бы уже мета-шаблонизатор.

Comment: @D-side, "нету" слова "нету", а сохранять скомпилированный файл в другом расширении нам никто не запрещает.

Comment: Приведите небольшой пример трёх файлов. jade, html и желаемого tpl. Для чего вам тут jade, непонятно же)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для сохранения скомпилированного файла в другой формат используйте [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename):

```
const
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    pug = require('gulp-pug'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename')

// Compiling Pug in HTML
gulp.task('views', function () {
    gulp.src('./views/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug())
        .pipe(rename('index.tpl'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
});
```

Экранировать функции можно через `|` . Ниже привожу пример с функцией PHP:

```
h1 FAQ
.summury
    details
        summary Some text
        p
            | <?php func()?>
```

Вышеприведенный код скомпилируется в:

```
<h1>FAQ</h1>
<div class="summury">
    <details>
        <summary>Some text</summary>
        <p><?php func()?></p>
    <details>
</div>
```

**P.S. Jade переименовали в Pug.**

Comment: Восхитительно, приведите пример параметризованного шаблона, скажем, рендерящего массив строчек, подаваемый снаружи. Что на входе, что на выходе и сохранилась ли функциональность.

Comment: @D-side ваш сарказм здесь неуместен. Вопрос заключался в сохранении определенного расширения. Впрочем, я добавил в ответ пример работы с функцией php.

Comment: Коль скоро автора вопроса удовлетворила бы "настройка" расширения, вероятно именно переименования он и ищет.

Comment: @Vadizar ещё как уместен, т. к. задачу преобразования Jade в Smarty, заявленную в вопросе, это в общем случае не решает. Но теперь вы как минимум продемонстрировали, что именно нужно для применения вашего решения, так что минус снимаю.

Comment: @D-side автор хотел узнать не как вставить функции-смарти в Jade, а как его скомпилировать в .tpl. Видимо, он знает, как использовать функции сторонних языков в этом шаблонизаторе.  Хотя, данный пример может быть полезен другим участникам.

Comment: @Vadizar из-за этой неоднозначности я и попросил пример, т. к. ТС уже вряд ли вернётся. (Хотя-я-я в последний раз он был вчера, так что это возможно; не факт, правда, что проблема для него ещё актуальна)